# How to convert a string to Json (or dict) properly when it has "\uxxx", Emojis, LaTeX etc in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-re

```
X = """{"botResponse": "Great question!  So you want to find out if \( \sqrt{44} \) is closer to 6 or 7. Let's solve this together, step by step! ️‍♀️

Step 1: Find the squares of 6 and 7. So, \( 6^2 = 36 \) and \( 7^2 = 49 \).

Step 2: Now, observe that 44 is closer to 49 than it is to 36. 

Step 3: So, \( \sqrt{44} \) will be closer to \( \sqrt{49} \) which equals 7. 

Therefore, \( \sqrt{44} \) is closer to 7!  Hope this helps!",
"quickReplies": ["Could you solve another problem for me? ", "Give me a similar question to practice? ", "Explain this to me using a fun example that's easy to understand "]}"""
```

I want to convert this to a proper `json` or `dict` format. How can I do as I've tried everything?

```
json.loads(X) # Error with and without strict = True / False
json.loads(repr(X)) # Error
json.loads(re.sub("\\", "SOMETHINGELSE", X)) # Still error
```

I've done the same above with `ast.literal_eval()` and still getting error.

Comment: It's not valid JSON to start with, you need `\n` not actual newlines.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for letting me know. Can you tell me the solution also?

Comment: Why start with a string at all? Write it as a dictionary, then serialise it as needed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It does work with actual newlines, see my answer below.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if it were possible, wouldn’t I be using that only. I asked the solution to this question because it’s the exact problem I’m trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will have to get rid of those backslashes, then you will need to enable control characters by using "strict=False". When dumping the dict again, you will have to make sure to set ensure_ascii to False, because your emojis will not be displayed otherwise.

```
X = X.replace("\\", "\\\\")
x_dict = json.loads(X, strict=False)
print(json.dumps(x_dict, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
```

That produces the following output:

> {
> "botResponse": "Great question!  So you want to find out if \( \sqrt{44} \) is closer to 6 or 7. Let's solve this together, step by step! ️‍♀️\n\nStep 1: Find the squares of 6 and 7. So, \( 6^2 = 36 \) and \( 7^2 = 49 \).\n\nStep 2: Now, observe that 44 is closer to 49 than it is to 36. \n\nStep 3: So, \( \sqrt{44} \) will be closer to \( \sqrt{49} \) which equals 7. \n\nTherefore, \( \sqrt{44} \) is closer to 7!  Hope this helps!",
> "quickReplies": [
> "Could you solve another problem for me? ",
> "Give me a similar question to practice? ",
> "Explain this to me using a fun example that's easy to understand "
> ]
> }